# Why can this variable "not be resolved"?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have two radio buttons as a radio group, and a "execute" button - so you select the radio button, hit "execute", and it dispays alternate dialogs depending on the radio selection. I get a error in the second-to-last line (creating the alert dialog builder) in the following:

```
private OnClickListener myClickcalcHandler = new OnClickListener() {
    public void myClickcalcHandler(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.calcbutton:
            RadioButton insideButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
            RadioButton outsideButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
            }
        if
        (outsideButton.isChecked()){
            //do what you want
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);
                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("some outside activity");
                button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emailbutton);
                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage(R.string.email_long)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNegativeButton("Close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
        }
        else if
        (insideButton.isChecked()){
            //do what you want 
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);
            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("some inside activity");
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emailbutton);
            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage(R.string.email_long)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNegativeButton("Close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
        }
            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            // show it
        alertDialog.show();

            }
```

so the eclipse editor just says "alertDialogBuilder cannot be resolved", and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

decalare AlertDialog globally  means outside if/else block as:

```
private OnClickListener myClickcalcHandler = new OnClickListener() {
    public void myClickcalcHandler(View view) {
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.calcbutton:
            RadioButton insideButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
            RadioButton outsideButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
            }
         //YOUR CODE HERE.....
```

Comment: hi - thanks for the prompt replies - I have tried these all and still get the "cannot be resolved" on the // create alert dialog
   AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create(); - not sure if it matters that i have used the alertDialogBuilder earlier in the script above the copied section, but I assume I can use it many times ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder` outside of the `if/else` construct, then define it within.

Like this:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder;
    if
    (outsideButton.isChecked()){
        //do what you want
        alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    context);
        // ...
    }
    else if
    (insideButton.isChecked()){
        //do what you want 
        alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);
        // ...
    }
        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        // show it
    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this before your if else.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = null;
```

and replace your

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

with

```
alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

Comment: hi - thanks for the prompt replies - I have tried these all and still get the "cannot be resolved" on the // create alert dialog AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create(); - not sure if it matters that i have used the alertDialogBuilder earlier in the script above the copied section, but I assume I can use it many times ? –

Comment: If you're still having issues, post the new code you're using, as well as the lines that contain errors and what the errors are.